# Dual-Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1 alongside Windows 7.  I wanted to check out what it's all about.  By the way, i actually like the interface a lot and the free office suite is very very nice.  I love how they can save to the .docx as well.  Onto the story:

I installed it using [**this**](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/) tutorial and I set it all up and everything and things were great.  I used the EasyBCD 2.2 Tool and created an Ubuntu 12.04.1 entry and when I boot the computer the Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.1 option show up.  However, when I click Ubuntu it does not boot.  It say and error and says I must put in the Windows CD to repair or something like this.

Here's my system specs:

- ASRock Extreme4 (EUFI BIOS)
- Corsair Vengaence 2x4GB
- nVidia GeForce 9800GT
- i5-3570K 3.4GHz
- Corsair 620W Modular
- 500GB WD Caviar Blue

I have no clue what could be wrong with it and I would love any assistance.  I am willing to mess around and if something happens wrong I can just reinstall windows and it won't be a huge deal. Thank you very much!

Here are my partitions I made:

- /boot 500MB
- / 10000MB
- /home 20000MB
- swap area 4000MB
- BIOS 4000MB

Answer (score 1):

Try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)-- Steps

Boot from a Ubuntu live CD or USB

Type these commands one after other

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Search for Boot-Repair in the Dash and launch it.

Then choose Recommended Repair..

Comment: Where and how do i access the command line in Ubuntu and also what are these doing?

Comment: Cool I see what's up I'll give it a go perhaps:]

Comment: Find "terminal" from the Dash. That should give you the console.